# i am trying to complete my assignment.which says In a Distance class create an overloaded * operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, variable-assignment

I am trying to complete my assignment.which says In a Distance class create an overloaded * operator so that two distances can be multiplied together. Here is my program:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class distance
{
private:
    int a;
public:
    distance():a(10){}
    distance(int x)
    {
        a=x;
    }
    void print()
    {
    cout<<"\n a = "<<a<<" \n ";
    }
    distance operator *(distance);
};
distance distance :: operator *(distance d)
{
    a=a*d.a;
    return distance(a);
}
int main()
{
distance d1,d2,d3;
d1.print();
d2.print();
d3.print();
d3=d1 * d2;
d3.print();
return 0;
}
```

But I get a compilation error saying:

```
'distance' : ambiguous symbol.
```

when I run it on VC++

But it runs fine on Turbo C (by minor change: `#include<iostream.h>`).

Please explain where am I getting wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your operator*() is implementing operator*=(), since you're assigning the result of the multiplication to this->a.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's already a function called `std::distance`, which you're bringing into scope through `using namespace std` and which clashes with your `distance` class.

Call your class something else (e.g. `Distance`) or, better yet, remove `using namespace std`.

P.S. This is a nice illustration of why `using namespace X` in this manner usually isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `using namespace std;` from your code, and prefix the appropriate symbols with `std::`. There is an [`std::distance`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/distance/) name defined for iterators in the standard templates.

(Your `operator*` would be better if it took a `distance const& d` as its parameter.)

Comment: I'll add that this is the reason why `using namespace std` is "evil" :-) Using it you get to live together with a very full namespace :-) (that get full-er every two/three years)

Comment: @mat Thanks ,it works ,from next time I'll be cautious before using "using namespace std".thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

`distance`is also the name of a template function in the standard libary. I strongly suspect that since you are `using namespace std;` it's ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to declare a name that is injected by another namespace in the same scope as others have mentioned. Because its name hides the namespace member, you can either use `::` scope operator to refer to your own name or you can change the name of your class. Assuming if you named `distance` as `distance1` you want to write your multiplication operator as:

```
distance1 distance1::operator* (const distance1 &d1)
{
    return distance1(a*d1.a);
}
```